# CAML index of option?

Tags: jsom, caml

I got a question regarding CAML and retrieving data. I need to determine the proper people based upon the places user submits.

So I created the lists People-Place where I have column Place and column User.

Now I would like to retrieve people from SP List based on the user Places choice. I was able to do it for each item separately - place A -> person A. This is easy with Eq operator in CAML.

Now I want to go a little bit further- user uses many places (place A, place B, place C). I pass the values into my retrieving function. I don't want to split my input string and iterate over asynchronous function. Is there any way how to check if the field with name People is a substring of Query value? In JS the indexOf function could do the job. Is sth similar in CAML or do I really need to use a loop?

Thanks in advance for you help !

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely Yes**, you can do this in CAML query also. You have to use tag name  while querying. See example

```
<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='User'>User_A</Value></Eq><Contains><FieldRef Name='Place' /><Value Type='Text'>Place_A</Value></Contains></And></Where>
```

Assume you have places like Place_A, Place_AA, Place_AAA, Place_B, Place_C, A_Place_A, ...etc. Now when you query this using above code, it will include all the places where *"Place_A"* is the sub-string of places name.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for answer! I am not really sure if I got this properly. Maybe I explained my problem wrong. The person is a field I want to retrieve e.g
Person A- Place A
Person B- Place B
Person A- Place C
Person C - Place D
The input values is let's say in form: (Place C; Place D)as a string.
Based upon this string I want to find my guys from SP List. For this example it would be Person A and Person C. I could do it by splitting string putting it into array and calling function i-times but I wonder if there is a CAML possibility (but without User like above)?

Comment: See, simply you can put any number of AND , OR conditions to your query. That is the way only. eg. place C, and place D you have split and incude them in query, one by one

Comment: This is exactly what I was afraid of. Anyway thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Contains filter in CAML query to get results.

```
<View>
 <Query>
<Where>
<Or>
<Contains>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
    <Value Type='Text'>test4</Value>
  </Contains>
<Or>
<Contains>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
    <Value Type='Text'>test3</Value>
  </Contains>
<Or>
  <Contains>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
    <Value Type='Text'>test1</Value>
  </Contains>
  <Contains>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
    <Value Type='Text'>test2</Value>
  </Contains>
</Or>
</Or>
</Or>
</Where>
```

You can build dynamic query based on your fields. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: This is the same answer as first answer provided